# How solidity computes 0.1 ether?

Tags: solidity

Since solidity has not float types, how does it computes products between "floating point numbers" and ints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The floating point value never enters the evm. Units such as `ether` and `seconds` are only for convenience, and will be converted away by the compiler.

For a simple test contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {
    uint256 public etherValue;

    constructor() {
        etherValue = 0.1 ether;
    }
}
```

We get the following (relevant) AST for the assignment:

```
{
    "attributes" : 
    {
        "argumentTypes" : null,
        "hexvalue" : "302e31",
        "isConstant" : false,
        "isLValue" : false,
        "isPure" : true,
        "lValueRequested" : false,
        "subdenomination" : "ether",
        "token" : "number",
        "type" : "int_const 100000000000000000",
        "value" : "0.1"
    },
    "id" : 7,
    "name" : "Literal",
    "src" : "103:9:0"
}
```

As you can see, `0.1 ether` has been converted to `100000000000000000` (1 followed by 17 zeroes)

Finally, this produces the following EVM op codes:

```
PUSH 0x16345785D8A0000
```

`0x16345785D8A0000` being the hex representation of `100000000000000000`

Additionally, solidity internally does have rudimentary support for [float values](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#fixed-point-numbers), although it isn't usable directly at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! So the compiler replaces the count with an integer.